# Chi-squared distribution probability with 2 var

Tags: probability, random-variables

is it possible to calculate numeric value of:
$$
 P(4X_1^2+X_2^2 \le 5)
$$

if I have 2 ind. rand. var.

$$
X_1 \sim N(0,1)\\X_2 \sim N(0,4)
$$

I can use the function CHISQ.DIST(x,n,1) in Exel to calculate $$P(X\le x)$$

My solution:

at first I make transformation:
$$Y = (X_2-0)/2$$

$$
X_1 \sim N(0,1)\\
\frac{ X_2 }{ 2 } \sim N(0,1)
$$
then I have:
$$
 P\left(4X_1^2+ \left(\frac{ X_2 }{ 2 }\right)^2 \le 5\right)
$$

$$\implies P\left(X_1^2+\left(\frac{ X_2^2 }{ 4 }\right)/4 \le \frac{5}{4}\right)
$$
$$
\implies P\left(X_1^2+\frac{ X_2 }{ 16 }^2 \le \frac{5}{4}\right) ?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for $X_1=U$ and $X_2=2V$ where $U$ and $V$ are iid with standard normal distribution.

Then to be found is$$P(4U^2+4V^2\leq5)$$or equivalently $$P\left(\chi_2^2\leq\frac54\right)$$
where $\chi_2^2=U^2+V^2$ has chi-squared distribution with parameter $k=2$.

(You go into right direction, but then just switched $X_2$ for $\frac{X_2}2$ which is not okay. You should switch it for $2\cdot\frac{X_2}2$.)

Comment: In your effort you started with $Y=X_2/2$. That is a good start. We have $X_1$ and $Y$ iid with standard normal distribution and inequality $4X_1^2+X_2^2\leq5$ can then be rewritten as $4X_1^2+4Y^2\leq 5$ (*not* as $4X_1^2+(X_2/2)^2\leq 5$ as you did wrongly in the posed question).